# Group actions and the possibility of physical interest for non-transitive group actions

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, group-theory

This question refers to the effort of conceptualizing a "reverse" problem: If it is meaningful mathematically to have a group(Lie) acting on a set $M$ and mapping the element of $M$ to another element on a different set $N,N\neq M$, *is it interesting from a physical perspective*?

Assume as usual a $G$-set of a linear representation of a group( the set on which the group acts is a vector space and the action respects the linear structure). We can then assume that for an element $p \in V $, where $V $ is the representation, we have $g \in G | gp=q , q \in V $. The action is obviously transitive.

Now, to a more subtle subject, let' s assume that the action is still transitive but we wish to point out the fact that there exists an isotropy subgroup of $G$, $H$: $H \subset G $ which we take as closed. The isotropy group means that $\forall h \in H | hp=p , p\in M$, where $M$ now is the general manifold- G-set. This means that now, we don' t care for a representation of $G$, but if $G$ acts transitively on $M$, and $H$ is the isotropy group, it can be shown there is a unique manifold structure for $M$ coinciding with the quotient space:
$M = G/H $. *But, as I see it, for the group $G$ to act transitively, it means again that for $p,q \in M | gp=q, g \in G $*.

Such a case is presented for example in non-linear sigma models and more particular to the low-energy effective theory of QCD for the interaction of nucleons. Beyond the immediate understanding of the usefulness of such an approach, and also it' s mathematical clarity, I' m trying to conceptualize whether or not it is meaningful to have a set M on which G acts and mapping us to elements of another set. The reason of this question is based on the fact that *for the effective model to work, we still need to suppose that G acts transitively.*

**Question**

So, is there meaningful at all to think mathematically that a group G may act on a set M and mapping the elements of M to another set N, and if so, is it at all meaningful and interesting to think like this in physics (not only for solving a particle classification problem, though not rejecting such a possibility) ? Would it have any use to think on such a basis on a problem like the effective model mentioned above, or exactly because it is without meaning, any such conceptualization is useless and so there is a straightforward way for thinking: we either find a suitable linear representation or a non-linear based on the transitive action of a group on it' s G-set.

---

- quoting from Weinberg's QFT-2 :

> The transformation rules make no reference to a particular linear $G$ transformation properties of the original fields. Indeed we did not need to start with a lagrangian that was invariant under linear $G$ transformations in order to deduce these transformation rules.

But, it still seems to me that we assume the group acts transitively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking if it makes sense, from a physical point of view, to consider maps of the form

$$\pi:G\to\operatorname{Map}(M,N)$$

with the property that $\pi$ is a group homomorphism.

When $M=N$, there is a natural product on $\operatorname{Map}(M,M) = \operatorname{Map}(M)$, which is composition, for surely the composition of two maps from $M$ to $M$ yields a map from $M$ to $M$. But what about the case $M\neq N$? What product can we take on $\operatorname{Map}(M,N)$ to turn it into a group?

So, to me, it seems that we have problems already from a mathematical point of view. Perhaps a physical argument that could go with this difficulty is that a group represents some sort of symmetry of an object (e.g. a manifold), and there doesn't seem to be a clear meaning for the "symmetry of an object that is mapped into another object".

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply. In the OP it is consider in a general fashion a group action on a manifold( a linear or not representation) and the question regards whether or not it has any meaning to consider the image of the group action not to belong to the G-set that is acted on; do you claim that not only perhaps physically but also mathematically this is ill-defined as a group action? Thanks again.

Comment: A group action is a way to associate elements of a group to transformations of some space. If you want to associate group elements to maps from one space to another, then this is not a group action. The difficulty of trying to do something like this is expressed in the answer above.